# Some of the Angular 17 tests are not executed

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine

I have an Angular app with some tests which contains also a library with its own tests, something like `app/projects/my-lib`. The problem I have it's the tests from the library are not being executed. Also, I try to execute a specific test from the library, I get:

```
ng test --include projects/my-lib/myfile.spec.ts

Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS (0.003 secs / 0 secs)
TOTAL: 0 SUCCESS
```

This is what I have in `angular.json`:

```
"test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "polyfills": ["zone.js", "zone.js/testing"],
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
        "preserveSymlinks": true
      }
    },
```

And this is tsconfig.spec.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

The tests from `src/` are working fine, but the ones from `projects/` are ignored.
I searched for different solutions, but all mention about some files which are no longer present in Angular 17, like `test.ts` and `karma.conf.js`.
Please advise what could be wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In a regular Angular workspace, you usually have a `projects` folder with multiple apps and/or libraries (https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries). The `angular.json` contains the configurations for all the projects you have in your workspace.

If you have a `my-lib` project, then you should have something like:

```
...
"projects": {
  "my-lib": {
    ...
    "sourceRoot": "projects/my-lib",
```

... and you should be able to run the tests you have inside `my-lib` with `ng test my-lib`. Hope this helps!